# AngularJS transition to abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I'm working on an application built with AngularJS that has two different states:

1. App intro wizard
2. App pages (with a Navigation template and nested views)

I want to default to State 1 the first time someone access the app, once done the wizard, continue on to the App pages, State 2.

My "app" state (State 2) is an abstract state because it has nested views. So I cannot transition to this state.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

  .state('intro', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/intro.html',
    controller: 'IntroCtrl'
  })

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.playlists', {
    url: "/playlists",
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
        controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})
```

Comment: So transition to one of the child states? And/or do something like this: $urlRouterProvider.when('/app', '/app/playlists');

Comment: @aet I tried this, but since my app State is using a side menu template, going directly to app/playlists didn't load in the menu.

Comment: @MarkK got the same issue any fixed solution for this. I'm trying to integrate Ionic Intro Tutorial with Splashscreen(http://codepen.io/gwhickman/pen/zpDFG/) with side menu application getting the problem.

Comment: @VinodKumarMarupu Unfortunately, not. I had scrapped that flow and reworked the onboarding to my app.

Answer (score 14):

I've got the same problem as you, here is a post about abstract state: [angularjs ui-router default child state and ui-sref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969441/angularjs-ui-router-default-child-state-and-ui-sref)

It explains why you can't directly access abstract state

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have added $location service to the controller of the "intro" page and use the following to transit to app state which works for me.

```
$location.path('app/playlists');
```

The menu.html is loaded and navigated to playlists.

Answer (score 0):

In a service:

```
$location.path(
    $state.href('app.some.abstract.state', { some: 'params' })
);
```

Or in a template (`$state` must be available in the local or global `$scope`):

```
<a ng-href="{{$state.href('app.some.abstract.state', { some: 'params' })}}">...</a>
```