# When ionic application launched appearance of default page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I want to make default my dashboard page.So write following code in app.js
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard')`

But when ionic application launch in mobil device,login page before show,dashboard page is appearing afterward disappearing.I want to dashboard page never be show before from login page How can i solve this problem.

Login Page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Kayıt Ol" hide-back-button="true">
    <ion-content class="padding ">
        <div style="padding:40px 0 40px 0; text-align:center;font-size:45px;color:#ff6707">
            Login
        </div>
        <div class="card list-inset">
            <form novalidate >
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required ng-model="user.email">
                </label>
 <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Email" required ng-model="user.password">
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-button icon-center ion-person-add" ng-disabled="!user.email && !user.password" ng-click="Login()">Login</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
 .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            cache: false,
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
  .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            cache: false,
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            cache: false,
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
```

Comment: its hard to understand..!'login page before show,dashboard page is appearing afterward disappearing' explain properly..!do u want : not to show dashboard if user is not login..!? and also update ques with complete state declarations..!

Comment: if user is not login, dashborad is not already show.But while ionic app is launching,dashboard is appearing and a few seconds after dissapearing.After that login page is showing.

Comment: have u used  $state.go('app.login'); in controller..!is login a state..?or Modal..?can u update your question with some of your code..!

Comment: Login page html and app .js code is sharing.I hope helps you to understand better.

Comment: Yasemin, can you please post your controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')`? then in `LoginCtrl` controller, you should check if the user is logged and then you can use `$state.go('app.dashboard')`.

But, maybe this is not the best idea. I am not sure about this but here you have a good answer with another method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32734632/2012904

And i think you are wrong with the use of the abstract property. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24969722/2012904

But like others said, post your code in controllers so we can understand your issue at all.