# TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined in controller with ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, bind, typeerror

I am stuck with this error and the thing is I am a newby with angularjs and ES6.
I have a controller for login which calls a service that checks if the user is registered on the database.
It seems I have a problem using **this**.
The message errors I get are these:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
     at ...

my **LoginController.js**

```
    class LoginController {
    constructor($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $q, SwapSvc, $state) {

        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
        this.$timeout = $timeout
        this.SwapSvc = SwapSvc;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.status = {
            loading: false
        }
    }

    submit(username, password) {
        this.status.loading = true
        return this.SwapSvc
        .login(username,password)
        .then((data)=>{
            console.log(`los datos recibidos son: ${data.nombre} ${data.apellidos} `);
            this.status.loading = false
            this.$state.go('main')//ir a pantalla ppal
            return data;
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            //tratar error
            console.log(`error, no hay respuesta`);
            this.status.loading = false
        });
    }   
}
LoginController.$inject = ['$state', 'SwapSvc'];
export default LoginController
```

Where SwapSvc is the service that checks whether the user is registered or not.

my **login.html**

```
<div class="app-container app-login" ng-class="{__loading: vm.status.loading}">
  <div class="flex-center">
    <div class="app-header"></div>
    <div class="app-body">
    <!--"spinner"...-->
      <div class="loader-container text-center">
          <div class="icon">
            <div class="sk-folding-cube">
                <div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
                <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
                <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
                <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="title">Entrando en su Dashboard...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app-block">
      <div class="app-form">
        <div class="form-header">
          <div class="app-brand"><span class="highlight">ReHand</span> Dashboard</div>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="vm.submit(vm.username, vm.password)">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" ng-model="vm.username">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña"  ng-model="vm.password">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-submit" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and **my route** is

```
.state("login", {
      url: "/login",
      controller: LoginController,
      controllerAs: "vm",
      templateUrl: 'pages/pages/login.html'
    })
```

Please help, I am completely lost...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: It comes from the call to the service: return this.SwapSvc.login(username,password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is undefined because you are not injecting your Dependencies correctly. `$inject` kind of maps the values in the array to the position in your constructor function. So, `$rootscope` will actually be `$state` and `$scope` is your Service. To fix this, you need to pass all your Dependecies in both the array for `$inject` and your constructor function.

```
constructor($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $q, SwapSvc, $state) { }

LoginController.$inject = [
  '$rootScope', 
  '$scope', 
  '$timeout',
  '$q',
  'SwapSvc',
  '$state'
];
```

Comment: You are right, I did what you say and then problem solved but now it doesn't go to the state 'main': `this.$state.go('main')//ir a pantalla ppal` plus after the .then if goes to .catch but it seems to have no error

Comment: You don't see the error because the code caught it!  console.log the err or throw it again.

Comment: I did it and now it says: **Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'main'**

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @BRJ you can not redirect to an abstract State directly. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969441/angularjs-ui-router-default-child-state-and-ui-sref. Also, if you are still having problems, you should create a new Question and mark this one as solved..

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem is solved! I have a lot to learn from AngularJS and Javascript.